# Kernel module compilation fails: No rule to make target droid/sunxi-livesuite-master/awusb''

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, make

I tried to compile `awusb.ko` on my Linux Mint with `make`

```
make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Dies ist Freie Software; siehe die Programmquellen für Vervielfältigungsbedingungen.
```

The `makefile`:

```
obj-m := awusb.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
    rm -rf Module.markers module.order module.sysvers
```

`make` stops with:

```
 makemake -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/ger/progentp/Flash droid/sunxi-livesuite-master/awusb modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic« wird betreten
Makefile:669: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** Keine Regel, um »droid/sunxi-livesuite-master/awusb« zu erstellen.  Schluss.
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic« wird verlassen
make: *** [default] Fehler 2
```

In my opinion with `obj-m := awusb.o` there is a rule for building the `awusb.ko` module.  Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the space in `/home/ger/progentp/Flash droid/`
Remove the space from the folder name, or move your git clone to another location without spaces.

Comment: many thanks for your response the problem is solved, i wish you a good time gerhard